# Is it "most" or "the most" or "most of time"?

Tags: grammar

What would be the correct usage?

> What activity do you spend most time with?
>   What activity do you spend most of the time with?
>   What activity do you spend the most time with?

Comment: I usually spend time _with_ people, but I spent time _on_ activities.

Comment: Do you mean something like: *On which of the following activities do you spend the most time: Cleaning your room? Bathing or showering? Cooking meals? ...* In other words, you want someone to answer with the activity they spend the most time doing compared to other things?

Answer (score 1):

The first is just wrong.  The third is the best.

Technically, the second is confusing, because it implies that there is a single activity where most of my time is spent. If we assume a person spends 8 hours working and 8 hours sleeping in each day, then no single activity occupies more than 50% (most) of the hours.

Now that sounds like a very pedantic reading, but even with additional context, it can be annoying. For example: "What TV show do you spend most of the time watching?" many people's response to that will be "uhhh I dont watch any particular show that much, I watch a lot of shows." Compare to: "What bed do you spend most of the time (sleeping) in?" or "What shoes do you wear most of the time?" These are questions that most people could answer.

Another way to look at it: "What TV show do you spend most of the time watching?" is a loaded question. It already implies that I spend most of my time watching TV. Compare it to "What spills do you spend most of the time cleaning up?" which will annoy me because I don't spill anything.

Comment: +1, but I don't think 2 is confusing at all. I think listeners would normally just adjust the scope of their expectations to mean what 3 does.

Comment: “The first is just wrong” — Er, no it’s not. “What activity do you spend most time on?” is perfectly fine. It doesn’t mean quite the same as #3 (which means “Which of the activities we are currently talking about do you spend the most time on?”), but it is absolutely grammatical, idiomatic, acceptable, and common.

Comment: let's address common. googling #1 vs #2 vs #3 gives me 42k vs 877k vs 126k

Tellingly, here's what the top hits for the #1 form look like: "americans spend most time" "indonesians spend most time" "indians spend most time" "narcissistic users spend most time" 

There's a reason for this. Nobody spends most time. Nobody possesses most time. Nobody spends most money, either, pretty much only a government could lay claim to that. Time is even more egalitarian. The #1 forms I found on google all included a scope for the (likely insulting) generalization to which "most time" would apply.